# Is it acceptable to ask a university professor to add his/her name to a paper?

Tags: publications

Is it acceptable/normal to ask a professor to add his/her name to a paper to increase the opportunity to publish the article in high-impact journals?

Comment: If that is the only reason, then NO.

Comment: In my experience,  some 'famous authors' are essentially quality checker.  They ensure the  problem is fresh, and the paper is of high quality.  Hence, their advice helps improve your chance to get published in these journals.  Also, they will not add their name to a poor paper because their reputation goes down the drain with the paper.  Hence, they choose only to be associated with excellence, and giving the impression that they seem to get high impact papers 'easily'.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus That practice as you describe it is against every set of authorship guidelines I am familiar with. That doesn't mean it doesn't happen, but it's wrong.

Comment: @BryanKrause  I'm trying to debunk the perception that including famous authors on a paper seem to get you a free pass into high impact journals.  That's what the question is implying.

Comment: To add to my previous response and on the issue of authorship, an experienced author will add his/her 'secret sauce' to the paper, and thus greatly improving the chance that the paper will be published in a journal.   This alone warrants authorship.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus "This alone warrants authorship" No, it doesn't. "Secret sauce" is not one of the criteria for authorship under any guideline I am aware of. If the contributions are substantial enough that they have made substantial impacts to the design, data acquisition, or data analysis, as well as being involved in drafting, approving, and taking responsibility for the paper, then they can be an author.

Comment: Op what do you think??? But it can happen.

Comment: @BryanKrause I disagree.  I never defined what 'secret sauce' is.  It could be substantial contributions, new interpretation of results, new analysis, complete rewrite, etc -- all of which meet the guidelines of authorship policy that I'm aware of.    If I managed to turn poo into a 5-Michelin star meal, I think I deserve authorship.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's not okay to do that, it is academic misconduct to have authors on a paper who have not made a contribution rising to the level of authorship.

There is no single central set of authorship guidelines, but you'll find them from various discipline-specific societies, universities, publishers, etc. Some examples:

http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html

> The ICMJE recommends that authorship be based on the following 4 criteria:

> Substantial contributions to the conception or design of the work; or the acquisition, analysis, or interpretation of data for the work; AND
> Drafting the work or revising it critically for important intellectual content; AND
> Final approval of the version to be published; AND
> Agreement to be accountable for all aspects of the work in ensuring that questions related to the accuracy or integrity of any part of the work are appropriately investigated and resolved.

https://provost.yale.edu/policies/academic-integrity/guidance-authorship-scholarly-or-scientific-publications

> Under no circumstance should individuals be added as co-authors based on the individual’s stature as an attempt to increase the likelihood of publication or credibility of the work.

https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0006/653883/Authorship-factsheet-March-2019.pdf

Under the category "should not be an author":

> Guest’ authors, who make no
> discernible contributions, but are
> listed to help increase the chances of
> publication;

All of these would ban the practice you are suggesting.